# JCheckBox messing up JTable's selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I have a `JTable` in a Swing application. I have a `JCheckBox` over it to toggle the visibility of a column. Now, whenever I select a row from the table and move the mouse over the checkbox, the selection of the table seems to disappear.

I also added a `ListSelectionListener` to the table in my application. When I normally select a cell with the table, it gives out two change events (one for mouse down, one for mouse up). However, when the weirdness described above happens, I get four events.

[image: weirdness 1]

[image: weirdness 2]

Here's a simplified example that produces the effect:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableSelection extends JFrame {
    public JTableSelection() {
        super("Test");
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "item", "another",
                "one more" }, 3));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(new JCheckBox("Example"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTableSelection().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Why does the selection glitch out like this (or does anyone know)? How can I make it work?

In case it matters, the Java VM version running this is:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT.** I discovered a weird behaviour of this. The effect vanishes completely when maximizing the frame and reappears only by restarting the application.

Comment: `add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);` tables can behave strangely when not added to a scroll pane.  Try instead `add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: I get four events. - standard events from ListSelectionModel

Comment: @mKorbel Why am I then getting only two events when the selection works normally?

Comment: there are two kind of events, from ListSelectionListener/Model and events from ButtonModel for JCheckBox

Comment: I hav(t)e to/will test on Win7, have to wait (multi_boot with WinXP/Win7/Win8)

Comment: @mKorbel Updated code and images to match current test situation. Seems to also happen with Windows look&feel.

Comment: haven't any issue, with, without L&F, I'm think that problem in your local PC

Comment: as aside your code in SSCCE/MCVE form doesn't corresponding with attn. images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to call `JFrame#pack()` after `JFrame#add(...)` and before `JFrame#setVisible(true)`.

> [How to Make Frames (Main Windows) (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
>   **Creating and Showing Frames**
>   4. The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes. An alternative to pack is to establish a frame size explicitly by calling setSize or setBounds (which also sets the frame location).

**1.7.0_72 on Windows 7 x64**
Same or similar thing happens `JButton` + `JScrollPane` + `JTree`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTreeSelection extends JFrame {
  public JTreeSelection() {
    super("Test");
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JButton("Example"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(new JScrollPane(new JTree()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //pack();
    //setSize(320, 240);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //You may also need to understand the EDT
    //EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    //  @Override public void run() {
    //      new JTreeSelection().setVisible(true);
    //  }
    //});
    new JTreeSelection().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for nice GPU lack, but on my side is not possible to simulating that (todays, lowprofile, physical GPU), with or without JScrollPane contains JList/JTree/JTable

Comment: @mKorbel I am running `Intel® Core™ i5-2400 CPU@3.10GHz` / `Intel® HD Graphics`.

Comment: Okay. The problem doesn't seem to happen on other computers. Thanks anyway, I'll try `pack()` when I finally get the app back on my laptop.

Comment: This is weeeird. `pack()` fixes the simplified example, but not my application... Gotta find something else.

Answer (score 1):

@not an answer Java7/Win8

`the selection of the table seems to disappear.` - I can't to simulating (should be an issue by using Nimbus L&F)

mouse_hover_over

[image]

JCheckBox.isArmed

[image]

JCheckBox.isSelected

[image]

.

.

Java1.7.0_67/Win7_64b

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: I put it in a `JScrollPane`, and now I'm getting all kinds of weird effects, like [this](http://imgur.com/a/HQg4i).

Comment: Okay. The problem doesn't seem to happen on other computers. I'll try the `pack()`  and header things suggested, though.

Answer (score 1):

Code runs fine on Linux, with or without the scroll pane around the table

I have to agree with Andrew's comment though:

- either put the `JTable` into a `JScrollPane`
- or make sure you add the header yourself as shown in the [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)

  ```
  add(new JCheckBox("Example"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

  JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START );
  tablePanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER );

  add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  ```

Comment: Okay. The problem doesn't seem to happen on other computers. I'll try the `pack()` thing from the other answer and this, though.